# Url.Action routes to the wrong controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I have two controllers, one Web API controller and the other a MVC controller. These two controllers have the same name and the same action name, though the one in API controller is a post while the one in MVC is a get, as shown here.

This is the API controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class SameNameController : ControllerBase
{  
    [HttpPost]
    public IEnumerable<*className*> SameNameAction([FromBody] *typeName*[] data)
    {
       // Detail implementation
    }
}
```

And this is the MVC controller:

```
public class SameNameController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult SameNameAction(int? page, int? pageSize)
    {
       //Detail implementation
    }    
}
```

I'm using `X.PagedList` to generate pagination. When I click any of pages, I receive an error

> HTTP 405 - this page isn't working

Upon further inspection, I realized that the URL generated is the issue.

Here is the problematic part of the view.

```
@Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)Model, page => Url.Action("SameNameAction", "SameNameController", new { page, pageSize= 5}))
```

Here is the routing definition in program.cs. As you can see, it's just basic stuff.

```
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

I expect that `Url.Action` would generate an url to the get action of the MVC controller. Instead, it generates an url to the post action of the Web API controller.

This is what I got:

```
<a href="/api/SameNameController?page=2&amp;pageSize=5">2</a>
```

This is what I expect:

```
<a href="/SameNameController/SameNameAction?page=2&PageSize=5">2</a>
```

I've never experienced `Url.Action` generating routing to an API controller. I'm not sure this is due to pagelist combined with `url.action` or `url.action` alone.

I can change the action name of the API controller, and the URL is generated as expected. However, this is not the issue. I would like to know why it map to the API controller and not the MVC controller to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I expect that Url.Action would generate an url to the get action of
> the MVC controller. Instead, it generates an url to the post action of
> the Web API controller.

Based on your scenario, I have checked your code between the line. As you know [`\[Route("")\] Attribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0#attribute-routing-for-rest-apis) always has the `higher precedence` in routing therefore, this  output`/api/SameNameController?page=2&amp;pageSize=5`is obvious. However, using `Url.RouteUrl` `HTML helper` you can overcome your issue.

**Solution:**

```
@Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)Model, page => Url.RouteUrl("default", new{httproute = "", controller="SameName",action="SameNameAction",page=1, pageSize= 5}))
```

**Note:** Please fit the code as per your environment.The exact code should be as folloing:

```
@Url.RouteUrl("default", new{httproute = "", controller="SameName",action="SameNameAction",page=1, pageSize= 5})
```

**Output:**

[image]

Hope it will guide you accordingly.